# iQaudio DAC-pro hat not recognized by ubuntu 20.04 on rPi4b

Tags: audio, ubuntu

I've added a iQaudio DAC-pro to my raspberry pi 4b running ubuntu 20.04.  I cannot find the dac in amixer

```
$ sudo amixer
```

Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
Playback channels: Mono
Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
Mono: Playback -2000 [77%] [-20.00dB] [on]

I get very faint sound out of the pi's base headphone jack, nothing from the headphone jack of the hat card's jack.

How can I cause ubunto to recognize the iQaudio DAC-pro?